# How to generate Android app key for google recaptcha

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64089795/13492963) refers to using Android App key rather than website key. When I followed to [recptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) I could not find a way to choose "reCAPTCHA-Android" as type .

I am receiving error when I tried flutter [sample](https://pub.dev/packages/grecaptcha).

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12008: Invalid Type of Site Key
```

and solutions seems to use the android site key, but could not find a way to generate those.